Module 'firebase_analytics' not found (Flutter/iOS)
I'm trying to use fcm with Flutter, but I'm getting several errors.
I'm running into an issue with my Flutter project, specifically when trying to build on iOS with Xcode. Here’s the error:
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'firebase_analytics' not found
/Users/song-yunseo/Documents/bubble_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8


Here's my current setup in the Podfile:
platform :ios, '13.0'
workspace 'Runner/Workspace.xcworkspace'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'Firebase/Core', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
    end
  end
end




try add config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0' to your Podfile, as same as platform :ios, '13.0'

check your ios project scheme, if exist multi configuation just modify your Podfile, such as:


project 'Runner', {
  'Debug-uat' => :debug,
  'Release-uat' => :release,
  'Debug-prod' => :debug,
  'Release-prod' => :release,
}

